# remove comma and some characters from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that can be in any of the format like below:

```
'xyz','abc'         //after conversion --> 'abc'
'abc','xyz'         //after conversion --> 'abc'  
'xyz'               //after conversion --> 
'abc','xyz','abc'   //after conversion --> 'abc','abc'
```

In this I have to remove `'xyz'` and if it has any leading or trailing comma.
Please suggest how can I achieve this with regular expression.

Thanks

Comment: So, you want to remove `'xyz'` with an optional comma before or after? What happens if you have `'abc','xyz','abc'`? Would you expect `'abc','abc'` or `'abc''abc'`?

Comment: oh sorry, did not consider this. This is a where clause for sql . so it must be 'abc','abc'

Comment: In that case, it's better to avoid regex (or only regex) and do a split -> filter -> join

Comment: @VLAZ or a non regex `String::replace`

Comment: @ScaryWombat how do you replace an optional comma of either side with a comma but not if the matched thing is on either end of the string?

Comment: @VLAZ Not quite sure what you are asking, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex alone is not very well equipped for this task. However, you can do the following:

1. Split your string on comma. In fact, you can split by comma surrounded by any amount of whitespace, in case the sting you get is `"'abc', 'xyz'"`, for example. You can use the regex `\s*,\s*` for that.
2. Remove anything that matches the string you don't want - you can use basic string matching or regex for more complex patterns.
3. Convert the split string into a comma separated list again.

Usign Java 8 Stream operations, this can be short:

```java
String[] split = str.split(("\\s*,\\s*")); //1. split into separate strings
String result = Arrays.stream(split) //turn to stream
        .filter(chunk -> !"'xyz'".equals(chunk)) //2. remove anything you don't want
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")); //3. convert back to comma separated list
```

The `.filter` predicate can be changed to whatever suits you - if you only want to match `"'abc'"` then you can use `chunk -> "abc'".equals(chunk)` or you can use `.contains` or `equalsIgnoreCase`, or even regex.

---

It might be worth extracting the filter rule out into a separate Predicate, so you can more easily change it, when needed

```java
Predicate<String> filterRule = chunk -> !"'xyz'".equals(chunk);

/* ... */
  .filter(filterRule)
/* ... */
```

Although if we examine this `"'xyz'".equals` is already a predicate itself, and predicates can be negated, so you don't need to write a whole lambda for this but just re-use the methods as functional interfaces:

```java
Predicate<String> stuffWeDontWant = "'xyz'"::equals;
Predicate<String> filterRule = stuffWeDontWant.negate();
```

This can all be inlined but it's a bit ugly, as you have to cast it into the proper predicate to negate it

```java
Predicate<String> filterRule = ((Predicate<String>) "'xyz'"::equals).negate();
```

The final thing can look like this:

```java
Predicate<String> filterRule = ((Predicate<String>) "'xyz'"::equals).negate();

String result = Arrays.stream(str.split(("\\s*,\\s*")))
    .filter(filterRule)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

So now you can more easily change whatever your filter rule is. You can even re-use this for any kind of list by just passing different predicate to use as a filter.

---

A non-Java 8 or non-Stream way to do the same to do the following:

```
String[] split = str.split(("\\s*,\\s*")); //1. split into separate strings

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(split));//convert into an ArrayList to allow removing

list.removeAll(Collections.singleton("'xyz'"));//2. remove anything you don't want
String result = String.join(",", list); //3. convert back to comma separated list
```

This approach can still be mixed with using a Predicate by using `.removeIf()` but this time it has to match exactly what you don't want:

```
list.removeIf("'xyz'"::equals);
/* or */
list.removeIf("'xyz'"::equalsIgnoreCase);
/* or */
list.removeIf("'xyz'"::startsWith);
/* or */
list.removeIf("'xyz'"::contains);
/* or */
list.removeIf("'xyz'"::endsWith);
/* or */
list.removeIf(Pattern.compile("'(xy?z)*'").asPredicate());
/* ...and so on... */
```

Answer (score 1):

You could chain some `String::replace` methods

```
String str = "'abc','xyz','abc'";
str = str.replace (",'xyz'", "").replace("'xyz',", "").replace("'xyz'", "");
```

**output**

'abc','abc'